# Integral of $x^2e^{-ax^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Hey guys I need to find the following integral using integration by parts and not the gamma function. Also there is an a constant a in the exponential function. So it is actually $x^2e^{-ax^2}$.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Take the $x^2$ and separate it as $x\cdot x$. Then use integration by part taking $x$ as the function to differentiate, and $xe^{-ax^2}$ as the function to integrate. Notice that $xe^{-ax^2}$ can be integrate easily because the derivative of $-ax^2$ is almost the $x$ that is in front. You would only need to multiply it by the constant $-2a$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}
\expo{-ax^{2}}\,\dd x} =
-\,\partiald{}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{-ax^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\partiald{}{a}\bracks{a^{-1/2}\
\overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{=\ \root{\pi}}}} =
-\pars{-\,\half\,a^{-3/2}}\root{\pi}
= \color{#00f}{\root{\pi} \over 2a^{3/2}}
\end{align}
Also
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x&=
\pars{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-y^{2}}\,\dd y}^{1/2}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-r^{2}}r\,\dd r
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta}^{1/2}
\\[3mm]&=\pars{\left.2\pi\,{\expo{-r^{2}} \over -2}
\right\vert_{\,0}^{\,\infty}}^{1/2}
=\root{\pi}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just curious to know how would this change if it was x^4*e^(-a*x^2)?

Comment: In the $x^{4}$ case, derive twice.

Answer (score 3):

Perform an integration by parts. Your result is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-ax^2}dx = -{x\over 2a}e^{-ax^2}\bigg|_{-\infty}
^\infty +
{1\over 2a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}dx
= {1\over 2a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}dx$$
Now you are stuck with an integral not resolvable by elementary means.  Either you use the $\Gamma$ function or the old polar coordinate trick.

Comment: You are confusing $\int e^{-x^2}$ not being an elementary function, with not being able to compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}$ by elementary means. The latter is totally possible.

Comment: I don't consider that arabesque "elementary."  It's quite an adhocery.