# A Solution for $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} x^2e^{-ax} \: dx$ without Integration by Parts

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I came across this integral while doing some physics. I'm familiar with the trick where you can solve the integrals
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-ax} \: dx \: \: \: \text{or} \:\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-ax^2} \: dx$$
by taking derivatives with respect to $a$, like in the first answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670221/integral-of-x2e-ax2). So when I first saw the integral below, my first instinct was to apply this trick because it is a much better alternative to integration by parts.

However, when I first tried applying the trick, I got

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}}x^2e^{-ax} \: dx &= \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2} \left( e^{-ax} \right) \: dx \\
&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2} \left( \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} e^{-ax} \: dx \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2} \left( \left[- \frac{1}{a} e^{-ax} \right]_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2} \left( - \frac{1}{a} \left( e^{-1} - 1 \right) \right) \\
&= \frac{2}{a^3} \left( 1 - e^{-1} \right)
\end{align}$$

Upon checking this with an online calculator, I saw that my answer was very wrong. However, through trial and error, I figured out a method that works:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}}x^2e^{-ax} \: dx &= \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2} \left( e^{-ax} \right) \: dx \\
&= \left[ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2} \left( - \frac{1}{a} e^{-ax} \right) \right]_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} \\
&= \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left( \left( \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{x}{a} \right) e^{-ax} \right) \right]_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} \\
&= \left[- \left( \frac{2}{a^3} + \frac{2x}{a^2} + \frac{x^2}{a} \right) e^{-ax} \right]_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} \\
&= \left[ - \left( \frac{2}{a^3} + \frac{2}{a^3} + \frac{1}{a^3} \right) e^{-1} \right] - \left[ -\frac{2}{a^3} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{a^3} \left( 2 - 5e^{-1} \right)
\end{align}$$

which matches the answers from online calculators.

At this point, I have an answer that works, but I'm not really sure why it works. My confusion comes in with the order of differentiation and plugging in the integral limits. In the post I linked above, they first used the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} \: dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$, and then evaluated $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}$ of the resulting function. In the problem I'm working on, I had to do the opposite (differentiate then plug in bounds of integration) to get the correct answer.

My suspicion is that this has something to do with whether the variable I'm differentiating with respect to ($a$) is in the integral limits or not. My theory is that in general, we should first differentiate with respect to $a$, then plug in the bounds of integration, but if there is no $a$ dependence in the integral limits, then we can first plug in the bounds, then differentiate. Is this correct, and is this backed up by any logic that I'm just not seeing? If not, what is the general method of using this trick that explains why in certain cases you can plug in the bounds of integration first, then differentiate, and in other cases, you must differentiate first, then plug in the bounds?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)?

Comment: For this infinite limit, you should do this: $\int_0^{\infty}f = \lim\limits_{b\to\infty}\int_0^bf$

Comment: Basically, you are differentiating (by $a$) a function that depends on $a$ in two different ways: (a) as a value under the integral, and (b) as an upper limit. And, as always, the derivative is a sum of the partial derivative on one of those and the partial derivative on the other. (Think of $F(x,y)$ and $F(a,a)$: $\frac{dF}{da}(a)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(a,a)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(a,a)$.) In your work, you are differentiating the integrand with keeping the upper bound fixed (to $\frac{1}{a}$), but you also need to differentiate wrt. upper bound, keeping the integrand fixed.

Comment: (Cont'd) Things get even more complicated as you are differentiating *twice*, btw. OTOH, the reason why the second solution works is that it ignores the limits completely, and then only applies them at the end. In essence, you are solving $\int_p^q x^2e^{-ax}dx$ for any *fixed* limits $p,q$ and only *then* you are substituting $p=0,q=1/a$.

Comment: You could find the solution in terms of an [Incomplete Gamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/) and simplify a special case of it. Would this answer be of interest?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I actually wasn't aware of that rule! It's exactly what I was looking for when I asked for a more general explanation of this trick. Thank you

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you for walking me through all the logic! For some reason, it didn't occur to me to apply any differentiation rules to the limits of integration (or in this case account for them by subtracting the extra terms after the differentiation of the entire integral). I also have a better understanding of my method that ended up working thanks to you. I never really commuted the derivative and integral, so I didn't need to account for the extra terms, and it didn't really matter that the limits were functions of $a$. Good to know different ways to solve the same problem quickly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $x = \frac{u}{a}$ so: $$\frac{1}{a^3}\int_{0}^1{u^2e^{-u}du}$$
Set $F(t) = \int_{0}^1{e^{-tu}du}$, to focus on the integral, and calculate the derivatives $$F'(t) = \int_{0}^1{-ue^{-tu}du}$$
$$F''(t) = \int_{0}^1{u^2e^{-tu}du}$$
We need to find $F''(1)$. We can immediatly calculate $F(t)$ and find that it is $\frac{1 - e^{-t}}{t}$. We calculate the derivatives
$$F'(t) = \frac{te^{-t} + e^{-t} - 1}{t^2}$$
$$F''(t) = \frac{-t^2e^{-t} - 2te^{-t} - 2e^{-t} + 2}{t^3}$$
and can finally sobstitute and find the solution of the integral $F''(1) = -e^{-1} - 2e^{-1} - 2e^{-1} + 2 = 2 - \frac{5}{e}$

So, the complete solution is $\frac{1}{a^3}\left(2 - \frac{5}{e}\right)$

Explanation:

$F(t) = \int_{0}^1{e^{-tu}du}$ has $t \in [0, b]$ with b > 1

We set $f(t, u) = e^{-tu}$ with $(t, u) \in [0, b] \times [0, 1] = A$

1. $f$ is differentiable respect t
2. $f$ is continuous in A (less is enough)
3. $f^{}_t$ is uniformly continuous in A (less is enough, for instance the uniform continuity in t uniformly respect to x)

In fact: $f^{}_t(t, u) = -ue^{-tu}$ is $C^1(A, \Re) (\in C^\infty(A, \Re))$. We want $F''(t) = (F'(t))'$. This exists in [0, b] because every consideration made on $f(t, u)$ can be made on $f^{}_t(t, u)$, too.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I never considered a simple substitution to start with the get rid of my problem in the first place. This works perfectly for me for this integral!